# Does founding a colony on miasma get rid of it?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

Just a simple question for a not too complicated answer.

Comment: Sounds like an awfully easy thing to test.

Comment: Close voters, please refer to [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one).

Answer (score 8):

I tested it and it gets rid of miasma.